# Ошибка при сборке проекта Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

Помогите разобраться что к чему,
вываливается с такой ошибкой

> Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$DelegateProvider

```
     buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'}
```

Comment: Помоему у тебя dependencies нет библиотеки поддержки v4.Попробуй в 
dependencies добавить implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'

Comment: Спасибо, добавил  //noinspection GradleCompatible
    и вот это
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0' и все пошло